# My code runs very slow

Tags: matlab, loops

Is there a better way of writing a nested loop? My code Works well but it takes about 7min to completely execute.

```
for i=1:Z
    n = 0;
    for j=1:N
        for k=1:M      
            if (Distance_Unique(i)==Distance(j,k))               
                n = n+1;
                Residual_Sqrd(n) = Residual_Squared(j,k);
                Summation_Residual_Squared(i) = sum(Residual_Sqrd);
            end
        end
    end
    Residual_Sqrd = zeros();
end
```

Thanks in advance. 
Darl.

Comment: An easy way to reduce the time is to initialize the size of the arrays instead of adding elements one by one: `Residual_Sqrd = zeros(1, N*M)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need more than a single loop. Use indexing, it should be faster:

```
for i=1:Z
   Summation_Residual_Squared(i) = sum(Residual_Squared(Distance_Unique(i)==Distance));
end
```

By the way, `i` and `j` are very poor choices for variable names.